# Solve sudoku by backtracking (java)

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

```
public static int[][] solve(int[][] input){

        for (int i = 0; i < 9*9; i++){
            if(input[i / 9][i % 9] != 0){
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++){
                    if(validNumber(input, i / 9, i % 9, j)){
                        input[i / 9][i % 9] = j;
                        solve(input);
                    }
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
```

This method should solve a (solvable) sudoku puzzle via backtracking regardless of the initial situation. It works like this:

Given a sudoku puzzle it iterates from the upper left corner over each row to the lower right corner of the 2D array. When there is already a number, it gets skipped. When there is a zero (empty field) it calculates possible values via the `validNumber` method. The first valid number (from 1 to 9) is put in the field and the method goes to the next field.

In this algorithm the method does not now whether or not a valid number will eventually render the puzzle unsolvable.

I want to alter it like this:

At the end, when the method finishes iterating through the whole 2d array, every entry of the array gets tested if it is a zero or not.

If there is even one zero the whole algorithm must go to the place where the very first "valid" number was put in. Now, the next "valid" number is put in and so on until there are no zeroes at the end of the algorithm.

I have some troubles implementing this thought. It seems to me there must be an other for loop somewhere, or something like a `goto` statement, but I don't know where to put it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a Sudoku solver once before.  It was a bit more complicated than what you had, but solved the game in a blink. :)

What you are attempting to do is solve Sudoku by "Brute Force" and using (tail) recursion.  That means you are attempting to solve the board by iterating over all **9<sup>81</sup>** possible combinations. 9 to the power of 81 is... well it's a big number.  And so your approach will take eternity, but you'll run out of stack space from the tail recursion much sooner.

When I implemented Sudoko, it was more straight up. It kept a 9x9 array of "items", where each item was the value in the square, and an array of 9 booleans representing candidates (true == viable, false == eliminated).  And then it just did a non-recursive loop of solving the board.

The main loop would start with the simple process of finding squares with only 1 remaining candidate. Then the next step would do simple candidate elimination based on values already assigned.  Then it would work its way into more complicated elimination techniques such as [X-Wing](https://www.brainbashers.com/sudokuxwing.asp).

Comment: This strategy requires a comprehensive set of rules to eliminate the numbers. Some "hard" level sudoku puzzles require complicated rules that basically mimic try-and-check approach without actually trying different combinations. I'm curious if your solver can handle empty puzzle as input. See my answer for tree-based recursion. I used it even for empty puzzle and it gives me a correct solution in reasonable finite time (seconds).

Comment: @Andrey - No, my solution couldn't handle an empty board. It was based on "process of elimination". And with an empty board, it would stop since there was nothing it could eliminate. My solution used 6 or 7 different process of elimination techniques. The only try-and-check approach it would do would be when the board was left with only 3 open squares and none of the other elimination techniques would solve it. The source code is not immediately available (disk is offline), else I would post it.

Comment: @selbie How did you handle backtracking? When using recursion, the stack tracks your move history, so you backtrack by returning to the previous stack frame. An iterative solution like you mention is more aptly called "brute force" than what OP is trying. Backtracking is not brute force at all. He's just not doing the backtracking part right. I'd be curious to see how your code can handle a "hard" board (like post in my code answer) on a modern desktop CPU. My code takes about 75ms on my machine. I don't think it would be solvable at all without backtracking.

Comment: @Andrey An empty board can't be "solved" since there are near infinite solutions. "Solving" an empty board is actually a different problem, namely the problem of populating a new puzzle, which is a challenging problem in its own right but is not really the same algorithmic problem at all.

Comment: The hardest true Sudoku puzzle (i.e. with only a single solution) known starts with 17 board squares filled in (the hardest ever solved by a human is easier at 21 squares). A backtracking algorithm with pruning can solve it in ~6M steps. This is far less than 9^81. And you will not run out of stack space, since the stack will never be deeper than 81 frames (actually, 81-17). Even if you didn't prune the search tree, and it did indeed require all 9^81 iterations, you wouldn't run out of stack space (though you'd never find an answer, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm does not actually backtrack. It moves forward if it can, but it never moves backwards when it realizes it's stuck in a corner. This is because it never returns any knowledge up the stack, and it never resets squares. Unless you get really lucky, your code will get the game board into a cornered state, and then print out that cornered state. To backtrack, you need to reset the last square you set (the one that got you cornered) to zero, so your algorithm will know to keep trying other things.

For understanding backtracking, I highly recommend a book called The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena. I read it when I was preparing for SWE interviews, and it really improved my knowledge of backtracking, complexity, and graph search. The second half of the book is a catalog of 75 classic algorithmic problems, and Sudoku is one of them! He has an interesting analysis of optimizations you can make to prune the search tree and solve very hard puzzle boards. Below is some code I wrote a long time ago after reading this chapter (probably not that high quality by my current standards, but it works). I just read through it really quickly and added the `solveSmart` boolean in the `solve` method which allows you to turn one of those optimizations on or off, which results in a pretty big time savings when solving a "hard" class Sudoku board (one with only 17 squares filled in to start with).

```
public class Sudoku {

  static class RowCol {
    int row;
    int col;

    RowCol(int r, int c) {
      row = r;
      col = c;
    }
  }

  static int numSquaresFilled;
  static int[][] board = new int[9][9];

  static void printBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + (board[i][j] == 0 ? " " : board[i][j]) + " ");
        if (j % 3 == 2 && j < 8)
          System.out.print("|");
      }
      System.out.println();
      if (i % 3 == 2 && i < 8)
        System.out.println("---------|---------|---------");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  static boolean isEntireBoardValid() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (!isBoardValid(i, j)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  static boolean isRowValid(int row) {
    int[] count = new int[9];
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
      int n = board[row][col] - 1;
      if (n == -1)
        continue;
      count[n]++;
      if (count[n] > 1)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  static boolean isColValid(int col) {
    int[] count = new int[9];
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
      int n = board[row][col] - 1;
      if (n == -1)
        continue;
      count[n]++;
      if (count[n] > 1)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  static boolean isSquareValid(int row, int col) {
    int r = (row / 3) * 3;
    int c = (col / 3) * 3;
    int[] count = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        int n = board[r + i][c + j] - 1;
        if (n == -1)
          continue;
        count[n]++;
        if (count[n] > 1)
          return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  static boolean isBoardValid(int row, int col) {
    return (isRowValid(row) && isColValid(col) && isSquareValid(row, col));
  }

  static RowCol getOpenSpaceFirstFound() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == 0) {
          return new RowCol(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
    return new RowCol(0, 0);
  }

  static RowCol getOpenSpaceMostConstrained() {
    int r = 0, c = 0, max = 0;
    int[] rowCounts = new int[9];
    int[] colCounts = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] != 0)
          rowCounts[i]++;
        if (board[j][i] != 0)
          colCounts[i]++;
      }
    }

    int[][] squareCounts = new int[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
          for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
            if (board[(i * 3) + m][(j * 3) + n] != 0)
              count++;
          }
        }
        squareCounts[i][j] = count;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == 0) {
          if (rowCounts[i] > max) {
            max = rowCounts[i];
            r = i;
            c = j;
          }
          if (colCounts[j] > max) {
            max = rowCounts[j];
            r = i;
            c = j;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return new RowCol(r, c);
  }

  static boolean solve() {
    if (81 == numSquaresFilled) {
      return true;
    }

    boolean solveSmart = true;
    RowCol rc = solveSmart ? getOpenSpaceMostConstrained() : getOpenSpaceFirstFound();
    int r = rc.row;
    int c = rc.col;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      numSquaresFilled++;
      board[r][c] = i;
      if (isBoardValid(r, c)) {
        if (solve()) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      board[r][c] = 0;
      numSquaresFilled--;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // initialize board to a HARD puzzle
    board[0][7] = 1;
    board[0][8] = 2;
    board[1][4] = 3;
    board[1][5] = 5;
    board[2][3] = 6;
    board[2][7] = 7;
    board[3][0] = 7;
    board[3][6] = 3;
    board[4][3] = 4;
    board[4][6] = 8;
    board[5][0] = 1;
    board[6][3] = 1;
    board[6][4] = 2;
    board[7][1] = 8;
    board[7][7] = 4;
    board[8][1] = 5;
    board[8][6] = 6;
    numSquaresFilled = 17;

    printBoard();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    solve();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Solving took " + (end - start) + "ms.\n");
    printBoard();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually `validNumber()` method will not return any number because there is no possibilities left that means one of the previous choices was incorrect. Just imagine that the algorithm is started with the empty grid (obviously this puzzle is solvable<sup>1</sup>).

The solution is to keep tree of possible choices and if some choices are incorrect, then just remove them from the tree and use the next available choice (or step back on a higher level of the tree, if there is no choice left in this branch). This method should find a solution if any. (Actually this is how I implemented my sudoku solver some time ago.)

---

<sup>1</sup> IMHO there are 3 different kinds of sudoku:

1. "true" correct sudoku that has a single unique complete solution;
2. ambiguous sudoku that has multiple distinct complete solutions, e.g. a puzzle with only 7 different numbers, so it has at least two distinct solutions that differ by swapping 8th and 9th numbers;
3. incorrect sudoku that has no complete solution, e.g. with a row with two or more occurrences of the same number.

With this definition, a solver algorithm should either:

1. prove that there is no solution;
2. return complete solution that satisfies the initial grid.

In the case of a "true" sudoku the result is a "true" solution by definition. In the case of an ambiguous sudoku the result can be different depending on the algorithm. An empty grid is the ultimate example of ambiguous sudoku.

Comment: An empty grid is *not* a solvable Sudoku puzzle. Sudoku puzzles only have one solution, which is the unique part of this problem. They are basically mazes.

Also, with recursive backtracking, the call stack is the tree you mention. You could certainly find a way to do the same thing with an explicit external tree, but it would be very awkward to code, and less efficient for sure.

Comment: @The111 I agree that true sudoku should have one unique solution, but other cases are also possible (e.g. published in papers or online). I added details to the answer. As for the algorithm, it's just an idea of it, not a concrete implementation.

Comment: Agreed. And a backtracking solver will indeed solve an empty grid instantaneously.